# Spring Security disable default login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like intergrate Spring Security in my rest API. I have problem because my configration blocing all routes.

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/getNews").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

When I want `GET` on `http://localhost:8080/` spring returns login form

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
        <form name='f' action='/login' method='POST'>
            <table>
                <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
                <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="5453a3c5-2573-4861-b777-d008b04863c3" />
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I have a rule for `/` to permit. Why I don't have access to my API?

Comment: Maybe try to manually write permission for Get request `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()`

Comment: Not working with this.

Comment: And `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").permitAll()` ?

Comment: The same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found next:

> When using `permitAll` it means every authenticated user, however you disabled anonymous access so that won't work.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33329438/8119498)

This works for me, add example:

```
http.csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().authorities("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, appConfigHolder.getSecurity().getLoginUrl()).permitAll()
```

*Edited:*

Problem was in Spring version. With v1.4.3.REALESE no problems.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/")`

Comment: I don't use `WebSecurity` but `HttpSecurity`

Comment: This code not compile. I try do this `http
            .anonymous()
            .authorities("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();` but it's not working.

Comment: I add your code and still the same error. I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4

Comment: I'm using v1.4.3.REALESE

Comment: Ok for this realese it's working but why 1.5 it's bad?

Comment: I don't know) Is this resolve problem? Maybe your code will work fine with older version of Spring?

Answer (score 4):

To disable the default login page (and thus disable Spring's basic security features), make sure your @SpringBootApplication annotation looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The important part is: `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })`. This disables the automatic configuration of Spring's security features.

I found this helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Spring Boot Starter 2.1.5 and Spring Boot Security Starter 2.1.5

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot user, You can disable the default login page by extending  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class and provide an access permit to "/login" page and Get request.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"*/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/login").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to disable the default login page of Spring Security, you can do like this:

```
   http.removeConfigurer(DefaultLoginPageConfigurer.class);
```

Both `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` and `DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter` will be disabled.