# Allowing static resources without spring security authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Hi I integrated spring security in my web application. My `configure()` method is overriden as,

```
@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/static/**")
            .permitAll().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
}
```

[image: My project structure]

my project structure is as in the image. But spring security is not actually allowing the resource without authentication. In `WebSecurityConfig.java` if I remove `.anyRequest().authenticated()`, it is allowing `css` and `js` for the browser to render. How to solve this?

Comment: `/resources/static` should probably be `/static`/

Comment: I gave `/static/**`, It is not working

Comment: You would also need to configure `anonymous()` to allow anonymous access.

Comment: Have you tried `@Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web ) throws Exception{
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/static/**");
 }`

Comment: @M.Deinum How to configure `anonymous()` ?

Comment: @CIPHER007 It is also not working

Comment: Is there any `regular expression` I can use. Like regular expression to match all file which ends with `.css` `.js` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327677/java-based-configuration-to-enable-spring-security-anonymous-access